# How Can I animate Bing map pushpins based on a live GPS feed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gis, bing-maps

I have looked over the bing maps documentation trying to find an answer to my question. I would prefer to do everything using the bing maps api and not have to add a third party library if possible.

**Question:** How can I animate a pushpin to make a smooth transition from one set of gps coordinate(longitude/latitude) to another in order to simulate smooth movement of a Pushpin on Bing maps?

**Question:** can deleting an entire object out of the map.entities array waste enough resources to cause performance issues? If so how can I change the pushpin latitude and longitude properties without deleting the entire object?

Sample code of trying to change the pushpins properties without deleting the object out of the array. This code does not work… I am unsure why it is not working?

```
map.entities.get(theIndexOfThePushPin)._location.latitude = newLat;
map.entities.get(theIndexOfThePushPin)._location.longitude = newLon;
```

I create a pushpin like so - This works fine

```
map.entities.push(new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lon), {
    text: text,
    visible: true,
    textOffset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 5)
}));
```

Pseudo code for my recursive angular $http call

```
    function BusMoveGPSRefresh() {
            $http.get(resourceURL)
                .then(function (data) {
                    if ('if pushpins have not been created') {
                        //create pushpins...
                        }
                    } else {
                        //delete pushpins out of the array and then recreate them
                        //with updated lon/lat. Or just update existing objects lon/lat properties if possible?
                        }
                    }

                    BusMoveGPSRefresh();//after everything is done then go get more info and start again. recursion...

                }, function (reason) {// if fail than do
                    console.log(reason);
                    console.log("This Is not Working!!! Dang!!");
                });
    }
```

Any insight into the problem would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a **simple** answer for adding animation. I did find a site that gave a step by step tutorial on a more in-depth answer on how to animate pushpins.

**Answer: 1** -- tutorial on how to animate bing map pushpins
https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/08/07/bring-your-maps-to-life-creating-animations-with-bing-maps-javascript/

**Answer: 2** -- this is how to update the pushpin location without deleting the pushpin object out of the entities array.

Instead of deleting the entire pushpin object find the pushpin index and then use the property "setLocation()" and then add a new location.

```
//check to make sure that the lat and lon have
//changed if it is still the same location do nothing. else update
if (map.entities.get(indexOfPushpin).getLocation().latitude != lat
    || map.entities.get(indexOfPushpin).getLocation().longitude != lon) {

    map.entities.get(indexOfPushpin).setLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(lat, lon));
}
```